# How to update an array of objects with data taken from the corresponding elements of another same-size array?

Tags: javascript, array-map

Say I have an array of objects as follows:

```
data = [
{
 "id":34
},
{
 "id":35
},
{
 "id":36
},
{
 "id":37
}
]
```

and another array as follows:

```
myNumberArray  = [1,2,3,4]
```

They might be much larger, but the number of elements in both arrays will always be the same. I want to modify each element of `data` by adding a `number` attribute, assigning it the value from the corresponding element of `myNumberArray`.

When done, `data` will look as follows:

```
data = [
{
 "number":1,
 "id":34
},
{
 "number":2,
 "id":35
},
{
 "number":3,
 "id":36
},
{
 "number":4,
 "id":37
}
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried any algo yet? It would be very helpful if you add that algo in your question.

Comment: Use a simple loop and update the object using the same index `i`

Comment: data.map( (item, index) => item.number = myNumberArray[index])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myNumberArray  = [1,2,3,4]

data = [
 {
  "id":34
 },
 {
  "id":35
 },
 {
  "id":36
 },
 {
  "id":37
 }
]

data.forEach((elem, index)=>{
  data[index]["number"]=myNumberArray[index];
})

console.log(data);
```

This should solve your problem.

**Explanation:**

I used `forEach` to iterate over the data array, `forEach` accepts two parameters, the current value at an index, and the value.

Since, yours is a one-to-one mapping, we are using the current index to access the value at the same index in `myNumberArray` and assigning that new value in `data` for `number` key.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

```js
let myNumberArray  = [1,2,3,4];

let data = [
{
 "id":34
},
{
 "id":35
},
{
 "id":36
},
{
 "id":37
}
];

const updatedArray = data.map((item,index)=> {
  return {
    ...item,
    "number":myNumberArray[index]
  }
});

console.log(updatedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myNumberArray  = [1,2,3,4]

let data = [
{
 "id":34
},
{
 "id":35
},
{
 "id":36
},
{
 "id":37
}
]


data = data.map( (x, i) => ({ number: myNumberArray[i], id: x.id}) )


console.log(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
for (let i in myNumberArray) {
  Object.assign(data[i], {
    number: myNumberArray[i]
  })
}
```